# Arrow color while classes are selected in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

If I select two connected classes in a class diagram, the connection is displayed in yellow:
[image: Two connected classes with yellow connection/arrow]
For copying purposes I want the color to be black.
How can I display the connection in black?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the same way you changed the color to yellow? In my EA selection does not change line color..

Comment: in order to find how to change line color you use help file, search topic "Format Toolbar" and there is the "Line Color" tool described..

Comment: Hi Wavemaster. Do change the line color of a connector just do a right-click on the connector and choose "Appearance". There you can configure "Line Color" and "Line Thickness". Or I missunderstand your question?

Comment: Hi @flipperweid, I know how to change the color of the lines. The picture in my question is the result of selecting the two classes (by clicking on them). I want to understand why EA does this and how to prevent this "feature".

Comment: Downvote without a comment? Shame on you, stranger!

Comment: @Wavemaster The downvote is maybe, because you've been missing some of the basics ...

Comment: In enterprise architect 10 I can't reproduce this scenario. Which version do you use?

Comment: I legitimately had this problem on Enterprise Architect 16. I find it confusing since the appearance of classes, ... can be changed using the paint brush symbol that appears when clicking on the class - the connectors do not offer that at all. Thanks @phil for the helpful comment. You should make that an answer IMHO to make it more visible.